# Google adsense changing window onload?

Tags: adsense

I added a media ad to a website I'm testing, and it's having a strange effect. With the ad, the window.onload event I set up never fires.

I'm not sure if it matters, but I haven't uploaded the site yet, it's offline.

Edit: I uploaded it to a server, and now it works. Is there any reason it doesn't work offline? Is it something to do with how fast it loads offline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use FireFox there is an add-on called Firebug that is extremely helpful in figuring out problems like that.